# Dropbox company download caching

Tags: dropbox, cache

Does anyone know If there is a way to create a local cache for Dropbox?

I have multiple users in a local network and someone from the outside changes/uploads a file to dropbox, the sync party is on. Every single user might download the same file at the same time. Just tried it, both clients downloaded the same size from dropbox.com according to the FW stats. Multiply 100MB with 20 Users and your line is gone.

LAN Sync seems to just kick in, after the whole file has been downloaded. There is not too much information on LAN Sync out there.

Breaking SSL open and using SQUID+Cache also seems to be off the table, as I understood there's certificate pinning in the app. Also, in the not to distant future, TLS1.3 would probably end this anyways.

In an ideal world one "supernode" would download the modified files and share them locally via LAN Sync, but there doesn't seem to be such a thing.